# how can you store a component inside an object? React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build multiple buttons each one with a specific icon. I've tried creating a object to store the names but I also want to store the icons and like this it does nothing. How can you store a component inside an object?

```
import React from 'react'
import './navbar.css'
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';

function Navbar() {

  const data = [
    {name: "Home", icon:<HomeIcon />},
    {name: "Explore"},
    {name:"Notifications"},
    {name: "Messages"},
    {name: "Saved"},
    {name: "Lists"},
    {name: "Profile"},
    {name: "More options"},
  ]

    return (
        <div>
          <div className="tweetpage_____leftsection">
            <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-logo-vector-png-clipart-1.png" className="twitterlogo____tweetpage"/>
            {data.map(btn => {
              return <button className="navbar______button" startIcon={btn.icon}>{btn.name}</button>
            })}
            <button className="tweet_____button">Tweet</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt should work fine, the problem probably exist in the `button` component in the way the `startIcon` prop is handled.

Consider this example to show the components being rendered as expected:

```js
function FakeIcon(props) {
    return (
        <div>{'Icon'}</div>
    )
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const data = [
          {name: "Home", icon: <FakeIcon />},
          {name: "Test", icon: <FakeIcon />}
        ]

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {data.map(btn => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <button className="navbar______button">{btn.name}</button>
                        {btn.icon}
                      </div>
                    );
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```css
body      { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
div       { display: flex; }
button    { width: 75px; margin-right: 15px }
body > div:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store like this:

```
const data = [
    {name: "Home", icon: HomeIcon}
  ]
```

Comment: then how can you render it? as a component

Comment: You need to using css to create a component button has `startIcon`

Comment: yes i've tried puttin it inside `startIcon`